# Python: why is this print automatically flushing to screen without flush()?

Tags: python, flush, buffering

I was reading about std.flush() in python. And I found this example a lot.

```
import sys,time
for i in range(10):
    print i,
    #sys.stdout.flush() 
    time.sleep(1)
```

It is often said that it makes a difference with/without the "sys.stdout.flush()".
However, when I called this script from command prompt, it didn't make a difference in my case. Both printed numbers to the screen in real time.
I used python 2.7.5 in windows.

Why is that happening?

p.s. In another example which printed the output through subprocess.PIPE instead of to the screen directly, I did observe a difference of the buffering.

What am I missing?

Comment: There is likely an answer to explain what you're seeing, but... Is there a specific problem you're trying to solve, or is this intellectual curiosity?

Comment: Your operating system is ultimately the one that will decide when to flush. Calling `flush` is simply a way to *guarantee* that the output buffer is flushed at that particular moment in time, but it may be flushed automatically by the OS even without calling `flush` explicitly.

Comment: @dkamins You caught me.. It's out of curiosity, originally starting from a real problem that I somehow solved but didn't know how. And after some more reading and experimenting, here I am.

Comment: @Doorknob It looks more like an answer than a comment. :) BTW I am quite impressed by your profile. Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `flush` will generally *guarantee* that flushing is done but assuming the reverse relationship is a logical fallacy, akin to:

1. Dogs are animals.
2. This is an animal.
3. Therefore this is a dog.

In other words, *not* using `flush` does not guarantee flushing will not happen.

Interestingly enough, using Python 2.7.8 under Cygwin in Win81, I see the opposite behaviour - everything is batched up until the end. It may be different with Windows-native Python, it may also be different from within IDLE.

Comment: AKA "non sequitur" :)

Comment: Is it up to the OS or the python version then? I use win7. BTW thanks for the analogy. I didn't realize flush()->flush is a one-way logic before.

Answer (score 1):

See [`stdio` buffering](http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/stdio_buffering/). In brief:

> Default Buffering modes:
>
> - stdin is always buffered
> - stderr is always unbuffered
> - if stdout is a terminal then buffering is automatically set to line buffered, else it is set to buffered

For me, the example you gave prints:

In `cmd`:

- all the numbers upon exit in Cygwin's python
- one by one in Win32 python

In `mintty`:

- both all upon exit
- both one by one with `-u` option
- `sys.stdout.isatty()` returns `False`!

So, it looks like `msvcrt`'s `stdout` is unbuffered when it points to a terminal. A test with a simple C program shows the same behaviour.

Comment: I didn't do anything to disable output buffering mentioned in the link. I was using python 2.7.5 and my streams point to the terminal (is it? I call it from the cmd window).